# How to build a hinge in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, realitykit

I would like to pin a modelEntity to another so it can swing. The fix modelEntity I do load from a usdz file.

[image]

This is how I init the "red line" from above. It does already have a physicsBody but I can not figure out how to pin it with one end to the fixed modelEntity.

```swift
let size: Float = 0.04
let flexEntity = ModelEntity(
    mesh: .generateBox(width: size, height: 100, depth: size),
    materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)]
)
flexEntity.orientation = Transform(pitch: -.pi/2, yaw: 0, roll: 0).rotation

flexEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(
    shapes: [.generateBox(width: size, height: 100, depth: size)])

flexEntity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(
    massProperties: .default,
    material: .default,
    mode: .dynamic
)
```

*The red line does not actually have to swing. The end goal is a line perpendicular to the base plate, regardless of how the fixed part is aligned in the loaded model. Unlike in the illustration above, the "fixed" part is almost never parallel to the base plate. I was hoping to find out the radius using a "hanging" entity and a hit-test or so. So even if you can't help me directly, please tell me what you think of the idea. Share your thoughts*

Comment: Maybe a parent `Entity` or `AnchorEntity` what will rotate is the parent dragging the child with it